# Losing form values during model binding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a data entry screen where we enter in records of promotional deals. On my development laptop, the page functions as expected without issue.

However, in our production environment, the behaviour is different when my page has many records. If I post 50 records - each consisting of about a couple dozen form inputs - to my MVC action, I see that only 42 records are actually being model-bound, and the 42nd record has missing data.

While remote debugging this action, I entered `this.Request.Form.Count` into the immediate window and I get 1000 as the response. That number is a little too round for my liking. Sure enough, if I interrogate `this.Request.Form[999]`, the value corresponds to a piece of data for the 42nd record.

When I am posting more than 1000 form fields to my production website, I am losing any past the 1000th.

My production environment is Windows 2003, IIS 5.0. Is there some setting in IIS or my web.config I can apply to bump up this limit? As I say, when I run my site with Visual Studio, I have no issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this KB article for information on why this is a needed workaround: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2661403

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="<LargerInt>" />
</appSettings>
```

If you're using JSON, you'll also need to pay attention to this value:

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="<AnotherLargerInt>"/>
```

Both of these do raise security vulnerabilities to denial of service, as noted in the KB article and related security bulletin.

Comment: Good job. Great answer.